# jQuery do action if bigger than but do it just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry, maybe my title doesn't really explain well what my problem is but it's a quite simple thing with some example code I guess. :)

I created some styles for a design (a design with high header which need to be compressed when a user will scroll down the page). To get a small header out of a high header I switch the styles of it by jQuery.

By now, I check out the scroll position and on a 'x' position the style needs to be changed. Al this works but my problem is, it will keep on changing the style because of my if/else statement I used, Kinda normal and logic with this statement, but I would like to know how I just fire this one time instead of every scroll height bigger than..

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {   
   position = $(window).scrollTop();
   if ( position > 267) {

    $('#heading').addClass('header-shadow');
    $("#heading-top").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    });
    $("#heading").animate({
        'height': 75,
    });
    $("#site-header").animate({
        'height': 155,
    });
    $("#container").animate({
        'top': 497,
    });

   } else {
    $('#heading').removeClass('header-shadow');

    $("#heading-top").animate({
        'opacity': 100
    });
    $("#heading").animate({
        'height': 248,
    });
    $("#site-header").animate({
        'height': 328,
    });
    $("#container").animate({
        'top': 595,
    });

   }

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look a simple flag based solution. A flag which could tell the in the previous scroll execution whether the condition was already handled or not

```
(function () {
    var flag = $(window).scrollTop() > 267;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var position = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (!flag && position > 267) {
            flag = true;
            console.log('true')
        } else if (flag && position <= 267) {
            console.log('else')
            flag = false;
        }
    });
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u3s9t/)